# Display pieSliceText outside google pie chart

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts in AngularJS. I am using

```
pieSliceText = value.
```

The problem is that, for smaller slices, the pieSliceText is not displayed. 
[This is the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk7s0.png)

I want to produce results something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AO0Y.png)

I do not wish to rotate the Chart (I read some posts which suggests to rotate the chart so that the data labels fit in properly and get displayed. **No, I need to maintain the chart slice orientation as such**).

Is there any option to display the pieSliceText outside the pie chart (similar to displaying annotations outside the columns in column chart)

```
annotations: {alwaysOutside: true}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `annotations` are not included in the [data-format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for a pie chart -- `legend.position: 'labeled'` is the only option that will display the values outside of the chart -- see the [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) -- you could try adding your own text, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41894377/5090771)...

Answer (score 0):

To show the small values use `sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0` in the `options`.

The caption of this type is called `labeled`.

See:

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
    ['Assamese', 13], ['Bengali', 83], ['Bodo', 1.4],
    ['Kannada', 38], ['Kashmiri', 5.5], ['Konkani', 5],
    ['Maithili', 20], ['Malayalam', 33], ['Manipuri', 1.5],
    ['Sindhi', 2.5], ['Tamil', 61], ['Telugu', 74], ['Urdu', 52]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Indian Language Use',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    pieSliceText: 'none',
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,             
    legend: 'labeled',
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```