# Is there a way to add subtitles in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to add a subtitle to my Google chart, but `subtitle: "Example"` does not seem to work. Is there a way to add subtitles on regular charts without using Google Charts? Currently, I'm building a column chart.

Comment: see the answer here --> [Add subtitle in AreaChart in google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41893055/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you for that!